# How to exclude a certain package in spring after startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-bean

I have a package like this: `com.abc.adapters.dto` and `com.abc.adapters.dto.nooperation`. As you can see there are two sub packages within the `com.abc.adapters` package.

I want the spring to component scan the `com.abc.adapters.dto` package if a `JMS` profile is enabled, otherwise component scan the noop `com.abc.adapters.dto.nooperation`.

The way I have coded the spring app is that it loads the nooperation by default, and then it loads the `com.abc.adapters.dto` if the profile is `JMS`. like this:

```
@Profile("JMS")
@EnableJms
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.abc.adapters.dto"},
   excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX,
      pattern = {
         "com.abc.adapters.dto.nooperation"
      }))
public class JMSProfile
{
}
```

My main application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.abc.adapters.dto.nooperation"})
@Slf4j
public class Application
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   }
}
```

But it seems like if I do enable the JMS profile; it still instantiates the bean within `"com.abc.adapters.dto.nooperation"`. Is there a way of telling spring to drop beans later on once it's initialised or something like that to what im trying to achieve?

Comment: what is the package of `Application` and `JMSProfile` classes?

Comment: You need to move the other component scan annotation to a class annotated with @Profile(“!JMS”). Otherwise they will always get loaded. Alternatively you could define all the JMS active beans as @Primary so that they always override the no-op ones.